# Python TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have array of words in 'newsorted' and array of sentences in 'sent'.
I need to print all the sentence in 'sent' that has at least one word in 'newsorted' .
Here is my code.

```
for s in sent:
    for w in newsorted :
        if w in s:
            print "------\n",s
            break
```

I get the following error when running the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "withreferences.py", line 181, in <module>
    if w in s:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you reveal the contents of **newsorted** and **sent** ?

Comment: Please give example input and output.

Answer (score 2):

A good way of doing this would be the following.

```
newsorted = ['the', 'me', 'you', 'picture']
sent = ["The man left the store.", "You are fun.", "That's me!"]

for s in sent:
    sentence = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha() or x in [' ', "'"], list(s)))
    words = sentence.lower().split(' ')
    shared_words = set(words) & set(newsorted)
    if bool(shared_words):
        print("------\n" + s)
```

Running this will output:

```
------
The man left the store.
------
You are fun.
------
That's me!
```

However, the error you are getting is most likely being caused by the contents of one of your lists. Without knowing what is in the lists you are using, we can't help further.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the objects in your array has incorrect implementation of a special method `__unicode __ ()`. If it returns int, there is an exception `Python TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found`. Check the types of objects in your arrays if they are all standard strings.